# Closed expression for the Green's function for 2D Helmholtz equation over rectangular domain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, greens-functions

I have to use the Green's function for the 2D Helmholz equation
$$(-\nabla^2 - E) \psi(x, y) = 0$$ on the rectangular domain $[0, L_x] \times [0, L_y]$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions:
$$\psi(0, y) = \psi(L_x, y) = \psi(x, 0) = \psi(x, L_y) = 0$$ in my calculations.

To get the Green's function I used eigenfunction expansion, so after the separation of variables and simple calculations we get eigenfunctions and eigenenergies indexed by $n \ge 1, m \ge 1$:

$$k_n^x = \frac{\pi n}{L_x}$$

$$k_m^y = \frac{\pi m}{L_y}$$

$$\psi_{n,m}(x, y) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sin(k_n^x x) \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_y}} \sin(k_m^y y)$$

$$\lambda_{n,m} = (k_n^x)^2 + (k_m^y)^2 - E,$$
so the expansion is:

$$G(x, y, x_s, y_s; E) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sin(k_n^x x) \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_y}} \sin(k_m^y y) \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sin(k_n^x x) \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_y}} \sin(k_m^y y) }{(k_n^x)^2 + (k_m^y)^2 - E}.$$

The only simplification I was able to do is to get rid of one sum by using the [known](http://www.greensfunction.unl.edu/glibcontent/node42.html) closed form expression for 1D Helmholtz Green's function:

$$G(x, y, x_s, y_s; E) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sin(k_n^x x) \sin(k_n^x x) \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_y}} \sin(k_m^y y)  \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_y}} \sin(k_m^y y) }{(k_m^y)^2 - (E - (k_n^x)^2)} = \\
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{L_x}} \sin(k_n^x x) \sin(k_n^x x) G_{1D}(y, y_s; E - (k_n^x)^2),$$

which is much better now, but I wonder if it is possible to go further and throw off the remaining sum? If it is possible and the closed form expression does exist, is there some general method of evaluating sums of that form?